# How to use endsWith with multiple values?

Tags: javascript

Is it easily possible to use str.endsWith with multiple values? I have the next code:

```
var profileID = profile.id;
var abtest = profileID.endsWith("7");

{return abtest}
```

In this case I would like to check if  `profileID` ends with a: 1, 3, 5, 7 or 9. Only if it is true, i want abtest to return true.

I know I can do it like this:

```
if (profileID.endsWith("1") || profileID.endsWith("3") || profileID.endsWith("5")
|| profileID.endsWith("7") || profileID.endsWith("9"))
 {return abtest} 
}
```

But I would like to try a cleaner way if possible. Does anyone know how to?

Comment: `(Number(profileID) % 2) === 1`

Comment: `((parseInt(profileID.slice(-1)) % 2) === 1)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd say [regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) is better here:

```
if (/[13579]$/.test(profileID)) {
  // do what you need to do
}
```

Answer (score 15):

You could try `.some`

```
if (['1','3','5','7','9'].some(char => profileID.endsWith(char))) {
  //...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can extract the last character of the string and check if it is included in an array that contains the desired values:

```js
if (['1', '3', '5', '7', '9'].includes(profileID.substring(profileID.length - 1))) {
  // ...
}
```